# Expand part of the path in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to list all files located in specific sub-directories of a directory in my bash script. Here is what I tried.

```
root_dir="/home/shaf/data/"
sub_dirs_prefixes=('ab' 'bp' 'cd' 'cn' 'll' 'mr' 'mb' 'nb' 'nh' 'nw' 'oh' 'st' 'wh')

ls "$root_dir"{$(IFS=,; echo "${sub_dirs_prefixes[*]}")}"rrc/"
```

Please note that I do not want to expand value stored in `$root_dir` as it may contain spaces but I do want to expand sub-path contained in {} which is a comma delimited string of contents of `$sub_dirs_prefixes`. I stored sub-directories prefixes in an array variable, `$sub_dirs_prefixes` , because I have to use them later on for something else.

I am getting following error:

```
ls: cannot access /home/shaf/data/{ab,bp,cd,cn,ll,mr,mb,nb,nh,nw,oh,st,wh}rrc/
```

If I copy the path in error message and run `ls` from command line, it does display contents of listed sub-directories.

Comment: Brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so this isn't possible in one pass. You could `eval` with all the security/reliability implications that has, but you'd be better off using a loop or array substitution.

Answer (score 1):

You can command substitution to generate an extended pattern.

```
shopt -s extglob
ls "$root_dir"/$(IFS="|"; echo "@(${sub_dirs_prefixes[*]})rrc")
```

By the time parameter can command substitutions have completed, the shell sees this just before performing pathname expansion:

```
ls "/home/shaf/data/"/@(ab|bp|cd|cn|ll|mr|mb|nb|nh|nw|oh|st|wh)rrc
```

The `@(...)` pattern matches one of the enclosed prefixes.

It gets a little trickier if the components of the directory names contain characters that need to be quoted, since we aren't quoting the command substitution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain a little how `extglob` works so that i can accept your answer? Also you may want to remove `/` before `@`. You said `@` matches one of the enclosed prefixes even though it matches each of those when I tried and returning correct result.